# How can I rig a cylinder so that when it's rotated its end cap will not penetrate the floor?

Tags: animation, rigging, drivers

I have a default Blender cylinder positioned upright atop a ground plane:

[image: A cylinder atop a ground plane]

How can I rig the cylinder so that can be animated to wiggle/jitter (perhaps procedurally with noise f-curve modifiers on two of its rotation axis) without penetrating the floor?

[image: Rotated cylinder on ground plane]

A simple parent-child relationship as in the image above is sufficient to rotate (and translate) the cylinder on 1 axis in either a positive OR negative direction.

**I'm looking for a setup that would allow me easily to rotate the cylinder on two or even three axis in both a positive and negative direction.**

I imagine this would be possible with some drivers applied to the XYZ coordinates using trigonometric equations but the math escapes me. It might also be possible using a particular bone setup with the correct constraints but my attempts to find something that works so far have not succeeded.

Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is no need for complicated trigonometry or drivers. You can do this with constraints.
**Constraints are faster than drivers and have no [security problems](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46899/30849) ([manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/scripting/security.html)).**

[image]

### The Cylinder Rig

Create the following bones. (Side view. Note, that the orientations of the bones are all the same.)

[image]

*CTRL_cylinder* has no parent or child. The other bones are in the following hierarchy:
**`floorRotation > orientation > DEF_cylinder > Cylinder (object)`**

- Add a Copy Rotation constraint from *CTRL_cylinder* to *DEF_cylinder*.
- Add a Copy Rotation constraint from *CTRL_cylinder* to *orientation*.

[image]

- Add a **Locked Track** constraint to *orientation*. The Target is *CTRL_cylinder*, with *Head/Tail* at `1`. Set the **To** field to *-Z* and **Lock** *Y*.

[image]

- Add a Copy Location constraint from *CTRL_cylinder* to *floorRotation*.
- Add a Locked Track constraint from *CTRL_cylinder* to *floorRotation*.
  Yet again, *Head/Tail* is at `1`. Set the **To** field to *Y* and **Lock** *Z*.

[image]

I suggest the rotation order *YZX* for *CTRL_cylinder*. Add a crazy control shape for *CTRL_cylinder* and set it to be displayed **At** *DEF_cylinder*. The animator can move, rotate and roll the cylinder. Optionally, the Y axis can be locked, if no twisting is desired.

[image: finished setup]

---

BONUS CONTENT

### Two Axis (Rocker) Setup

This is useful for objects with two or more pivots, like feet, chairs, ... or a cube.

1. Create the following setup. The CTRL_cube is not in the hierarchy. The other bones are parented as such:
   **`y_copy > frontPivot > backPivot > DEF_cube > Cube (object)`**
   [image]
2. The rotation order of *CTRL_cube* is *XYZ* with Z locked.

   - Add a Copy Location constraint from *CTRL_cube* to *y_copy*.
   - Add a Copy Rotation constraint from *CTRL_cube* to *y_copy* with only **Y** checked and *Local Space* for *Target* and *Owner*.
3. - Add a Copy Rotation constraint from the *CTRL_cube* to *frontPivot*.
   - Add a Copy Rotation constraint from the *CTRL_cube* to *backPivot*.
     [image]
4. Finally, limit the rotation of the *frontPivot*, to prevent the cube from going under the floor.

   - Add a Limit Rotation constraint to the *frontPivot* in *Local Space*, *For Transform* and with the *X Limits* `0` and `90`.
     [image]

The result can be moved rotated and rocked from front to back. With additional pivots and their respective Limit Rotation constraints any number of edges can be available for rocking.

[image]
<sup>Added a stylisch Bone Shape for CTRL_cube **At** DEF_Cube.</sup>

Comment: This is fantastic, exactly what I need! Thank you! I cannot award the bounty for another 13 hours but will do so then.

Comment: @BlenderBro Leave the bounty open, someone could come up with an even more fitting answer.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't seem you would need complex trigonometric equations here. You only wish to keep the object above ground(or on the ground), let's do just that.

## Using a Driver

You can set up a driver for z location with a scripted function that finds the lowest vertex and then adjusts the location of the object accordingly:

```
import bpy

def aboveGround(object_name,floor_z):
    obj = bpy.data.objects[object_name]
    mesh = obj.data
    z = 7 # because it's a lucky number... 
          # ...and 0 seems to be buggy inside the driver for some reason
    for verts in mesh.vertices:
        world_space_co = obj.matrix_world * verts.co
        if world_space_co[2] < z :
            z = world_space_co[2]
            
    loc_z = obj.location[2] 
    
    return loc_z - z + floor_z   
#    # or this if we don't want the object to stick to the ground when it's above :
#    if z<floor_z:
#        return loc_z - z + floor_z
#    else:
#        return loc_z

# add function to driver_namespace
bpy.app.driver_namespace['aboveGround'] = aboveGround
```

You would need to have this in a text block and check Register (Autorun Python Script will need to be enabled in the user preferences as well) so it runs when you open the file:

[image: check Register]

You can just run it manually as well.

Then you can create a driver for z location of your object and put the function as the expression:
[image: create a driver for z location of your object and put the function as the expression]

[image]

---

## Using a Scene Update App Handler

It would also be possible to have only a function that would correct the position while working so you could set keyframes. Sort of like a tool. You could use a scene update app handler for that. You could just register it when you need it and then remove it once you don't need it any more:

```
import bpy


def AboveGroundHandler(scene):
    obj = bpy.data.objects['Plane']
    mesh = obj.data
    floor_z = 0
    z = 7 
    for verts in mesh.vertices:
        world_space_co = obj.matrix_world * verts.co
        if world_space_co[2] < z :
            z = world_space_co[2]
              
    obj.location[2] = obj.location[2] - z + floor_z   

bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.append(AboveGroundHandler)
#bpy.app.handlers.scene_update_pre.clear() # to remove it(can be run from Python console)
```

Comment: Thanks for great script! I want to say, if driver expression produces error after opening a file, just add ".py" after script name in text editor (w/o quotes)

Comment: (I wrote a trig. version of your driver, but for cylinders only, so it's not as general as yours, and  not worth posting.).. What triggers  a scene_update_pre handler? Would it work during interpolation between key frames?

Comment: I believe drivers are intended for use in animation, I think it would be better to use them. I just thought, that if there is a cylinder wiggling it might bounce up and down so if one wanted to animate it manually, that could be simplified using this handler method as a simple tool for just placing the object in correct positions while the keyframes are set - that was the thought process. I think it might lead to unexpected results if used in animation.

Comment: A really interesting, general purpose solution, thank you! I gotta go with Leander's constraint setup though due to its comparative ease of use, and for the reasons stated at the top of their answer.

Comment: Leander's solution is really great. That would probably be my choice as well. I don't do much animation, so I did not think of it.