# My bone keeps on rotating. Need a little help with constraints

Tags: armature, bones, constraints

I'm trying to figure out how to rotate a rectangle box, and rotate all the parent bones along with the box so it can rotate a second time around another edge, and a third, and so on.

[image]

I tried to achieve it with constraints. But whenever I rotate a bone (even just 12 degrees) it keeps rotating on and on. I just want a solid 90 degrees rotation, but long story short, my bones are out of control.

Probably it has a lot to do with my whole constraint setup, but after fooling around for quite a while now, I'm desperate for some help and understanding.

Hope someone can help.

Project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/c024bphti54koey/RectangleBox.blend?dl=0

Comment: question: I can't move your armature, only its origin, what's the settings that allows you to move the origin in 2.8? Also, maybe you should simply ask: how to make a box that can roll on any of its angle, something like that?

Comment: What do you mean with origin? Maybe it is because the armature is in rest position instead of pose position? I can move all the bones.

I asked the question you mentioned several times but the question got downvoted/canceled by a moderator constantly referening to this already existing question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/119677/how-can-i-rig-a-cylinder-so-that-when-its-rotated-its-end-cap-will-not-penetrat

Comment: Do you know what a [dependency cycle](http://julienduroure.com/en/2014/12/dependency-cycle-detected/) is? If not, please read that page.

Comment: This link is exactly what I need. Although I suspected some of these dependency links where the problem but hoped someone might see where the exact problem is, this is still very helpful. Hope to fix my armature soon with this new knowledge. Thank you very much.

Comment: haha ps reading the link you applied now, seeing exactly all the stuff I did as examples of  'buggy' and impossible. Big lesson learned here. THNX